# Overleaf like compilation check in emacs

Tags: latex, auctex

When I am writing in latex in emacs I have to press C-c C-l to see the compilation log or use `M-x TeX-error-overview` to see the errors. Overleaf does have a handy feature, which lets the symbol turn red as soon as there is an error (depicted in the image). For now I can resort to `M-x TeX-error-overview`.

[image: Overleaf compile error]

Is there a possibility (some useful package) to have the light bulb indicators for latex compliation similar to the python compilation bulbs in the image below?
[image: Spacemacs panel]